# -exec wc -l {} \; prints count and path, I just need count

Tags: bash, exec, wc

```sh
Lines=(find $FILEDIRECTORY -iname "*$FILEENDING" -exec wc -l {} \;)
```

The User can put in his path and file ending and it should count how many  lines each program has... if User just `wc -l` it prints me out how man files I have with that file ending what I want is:

```
100
78
45
```

So from every file the lines

Comment: I was trinken to use this array and another array which counts the lines that have one-lined comments... but the Look does not work:#counts the percentage of commentslines                                                                   for (( i=0; i < ${#Lines[*]}; i++ )); do Percentage[i]=$((100*Comments[i]/Lines[i])) echo ${Percentage[i]}                                                            
 done                                                                                    do have maybe any idea why its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```
find $FILEDIRECTORY -iname "*$FILEENDING" -exec \
sh -c 'for f; do wc -l < "$f"; done' _ {} +
```

Please understand that:

- `wc -l < file` only prints line count without filename
- `+` after `exec` is much more efficient than `\;` as `find` tries to pass multiple files in argument.
- `for f` is shorthand for `for f in "$@"`

---

**Altenative Solution:**

```sh
find $FILEDIRECTORY -iname "*$FILEENDING" -exec grep -hc '^' {} +
```

If `+` doesn't work in your `find` then use:

```sh
find $FILEDIRECTORY -iname "*$FILEENDING" -exec grep -hc '^' {} \;
```